# MySql joining 3 tables on condition

Tags: mysql, relational-database

Im looking to expand on the knowledge I already have in MySql (it is not that much ), so I download a sample database from : http://downloads.mysql.com/docs/sakila-db.zip , and start to play with, my q that is there a way to join these tables ( actor, film, film-actor ) to have a table that show each actor with the films he act on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These tables have many-to-many relationship, to show each actor with the films you can use this query -

```
SELECT
  a.actor_id,
  a.first_name,
  a.last_name,
  f.film_id,
  f.title
FROM actor a
  INNER JOIN film_actor fa
    ON fa.actor_id = a.actor_id
  INNER JOIN film f
    ON f.film_id = fa.film_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a modified query of Devart. If you want to have a result with `Actor_ID`, *concactenated* `ActorName`  and *concactenated* `TITLE` then you should try this one:

```
SELECT
        a.actor_id,
        CONCAT(a.first_name,' ',a.last_name) AS ActorName,
        GROUP_CONCAT(f.title) Titles
FROM actor a
        INNER JOIN film_actor fa
          ON fa.actor_id = a.actor_id
        INNER JOIN film f
          ON f.film_id = fa.film_id
GROUP BY actor_id
```